# Flask-SQLAlchemy throwing AttributeError (relationship 'tags' expects a class or a mapper argument)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Working on a little side project with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy but I seem to have run into some trouble. I'm trying to create two objects with a many-to-many relationship on MySQL. But I keep getting a very weird error:

```
ArgumentError: relationship 'tags' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)
```

This is even though the code looks pretty much the same as the one in the [Flask-SQLAlchemy "tutorial"](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#many-to-many-relationships).

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('nation_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('nation_event.id'))
)

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class NationEvent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    tags =  db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,
        backref=db.backref('nationevents', lazy='dynamic'))
```

I've tried reading through the SQLAlchemy docs as well as the Flask-SQLAlchemy docs but I really can't find any way to solve this issue. I'd be grateful for any help anyone could offer.

**Update:** Dropping the entire database and remaking it with another name solved the issue for some reason. I can't really find a reason as to why it wouldn't work when remaking the database with the same name, though...

Comment: What SQLAlchemy version are you using?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm using 0.9.1, the latest I think.

Comment: It could be that something broke between Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy 0.9.x (it only came out this month).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point! Tried downgrading (all the way to 0.8.4) but getting the same error, although more verbose.

`ArgumentError: Class object expected, got 'Table('tags', MetaData(bind=None), Column('tag_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('tag.id'), table=<tags>), Column('nation_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('nationevent.id'), table=<tags>), schema=None)'`

Comment: Try to put a class name `Tag` instead of `"Tag"` string as a first argument to the `db.relationship(Tag, ...)`

Comment: Interestingly enough, I am not able to reproduce your issue with [the minimal test case](https://gist.github.com/svieira/ddf3a5c7ebc93967b235).  It may be caused by something else entirely.

Comment: @van That didn't make a difference, sadly :/

Comment: @SeanVieira Very interesting. Even more interesting is that the error has disappeared when I dropped and remade the database under another name. I've tried dropping the database and remaking all the tables under the same name before, but not under another name. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @hav - unfortunately, your issue has got me stumped.